# Java - How to modify an array within a for loop and have it be remembered after the for loop exits?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, for-loop

The idea of this program is to sort the input array from smallest to largest number.

So, I'm having some issues with my overall method as well as having the 'result' array be remembered after the for loop exits. When I try to call the method, it doesn't seem as though result is saved.

Also, for some reason I'm getting 0 and 13 as values of the result array, even though these are not values of the original array, I'm not sure where these come from or how I got them.

```
public static int[] sortMe(int[] inputArray){
 int[] result = new int[inputArray.length];
   for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length - 1; i++){
      for(int j=0; j <inputArray.length - 1; j++){
            if (inputArray[j] > inputArray[j+1]){
                int temp = inputArray[j];
                result[j] = inputArray[j+1];
                result[j+1] = temp;
          }
        }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: your sorting algorithm is semantically incorrect

Answer (score 2):

Your method returns the result.
So, from outside the method, call it and assign the result back to the original array. Something like this:

```
int[] myArray = new int[]{3,1,5,4,2};
myArray = sort(myArray);
```

There are a few issues with your method:

1) The 0 values are occurring because you are not sorting correctly and when creating the initial result array, by default all values within the array are initialized to zeros.

2) Also, you don't need the intermediate result array at all, just modify the inputArray directly.

3) In addition, your return statement was located within the outer for loop, causing it to return the result after iterating only 1 time. It needs to be moved outside of both for loops.

I have adjusted your method code with the following working result:

```
public static int[] sortMe(int[] inputArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < inputArray.length - 1; j++) {
            if (inputArray[j] > inputArray[j + 1]) {
                int temp = inputArray[j];
                inputArray[j] = inputArray[j + 1];
                inputArray[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return inputArray;
}
```

Comment: To call the method I have something similar to that, but for some reason it doesn't print... though the other methods work fine

Answer (score 0):

The code `int[] result = new int[inputArray.length];` creates a new array and initializes all the elements to 0. Hence, if some consecutive elements are already sorted, they don't process the inner loop and these elements of result array remains 0. 
For example, for the array {4,6,1,9} ,I get {0,1,6,0} as result.
For your case, its better to copy the contents of the input array to the result array.

Also, checking for consecutive elements only doesn't work well in your case.
For the array {4,6,1,9} ,comparing only consecutive elements will give {4,1,6,9} as result. So, thinking a different approach is required.

Secondly, it seems the method throws a compilation error since it misses a return statement after the closure of 'i' for loop.